# Calling pj_thread_register from python

Tags: python, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm trying to use pjsip via pjsua2 in python. 
I have a problem with threading.

```
import pjsua2 as pj
import threading

# pjsua2 test function
def pjsua2_test():
  # Create and initialize the library
  ep = pj.Endpoint()
  ep.libCreate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pjsuadaemonthread = threading.Thread(name='PJSUA',
                      target=pjsua2_test)
  pjsuadaemonthread.start()
  ep = pj.Endpoint()
  ep.libHandleEvents(10)
```

I get this error:

```
python3: ../src/pj/os_core_unix.c:692: pj_thread_this: Assertion `!"Calling pjlib from unknown/external thread. You must " "register external threads with pj_thread_register() " "before calling any pjlib functions."' failed.
```

How do I call pj_thread_register(), from python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax to pj_thread_register():

```
ep.libRegisterThread('PJSUA')
```

Unfortunately even if you call libRegisterThread it does not seem compatible with python threading.

I think this is because pjsip internally uses threads of type pj_thread_t and python threads are not of type pj_thread_t.

For more info take a look at Endpoint::libRegisterThread in the pjsip source code.

However, if you just want to run pjsip on a different thread, the code below may help.  It runs pjsip on a background thread named 'PJSUA-THREAD'.  The key is to call libCreate() on a different thread like I do below.

```
'''Tests running PJSUA2 in a different thread'''
import logging
import threading
import pjsua2

date_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S'
log_format = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(threadName)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, datefmt=date_fmt, level=logging.DEBUG)

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

THREAD_NAME = "PJSUA-THREAD"

def main():
    _logger.debug("entered main()")
    pjsuadaemonthread = threading.Thread(name=THREAD_NAME, target=pjsua2_test)
    pjsuadaemonthread.start()
    _logger.debug("thread started")
    pjsuadaemonthread.join()

# pjsua2 test function
def pjsua2_test():
    # NOTE: PjSip will initialize and run on PJSUA-THREAD, see logs
    ep = pjsua2.Endpoint()
    ep.libCreate()
    _logger.debug("after libCreate()")
    ep_cfg = pjsua2.EpConfig()
    ep_cfg.uaConfig.mainThreadOnly = False
    ep_cfg.uaConfig.threadCnt = 1
    ep.libInit(ep_cfg)
    _logger.debug("after libInit(ep_cfg)")
    ep.libStart()
    _logger.debug("after libStart()")
    iter_count = 0
    event_count = 0
    while iter_count < 10:
        event_count += ep.libHandleEvents(10)
        _logger.debug("iter_count %d (%d events processed)", iter_count, event_count)
        iter_count += 1
    ep.libDestroy()
    _logger.debug("after ep.libDestroy()")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    _logger.debug("after main()")
```

Here is the log output.  You can see pjsip is running on thread PJSUA-THREAD.

```
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.259 MainThread __main__.main entered main()
14:49:43.261         os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.8 for POSIX initialized
14:49:43.261         sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
14:49:43.262                  pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x7fd530013550)
14:49:43.262         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
14:49:43.262        sip_transport.c  .Transport manager created.
14:49:43.262           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.262 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test after libCreate()
14:49:43.262         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
14:49:43.263         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
14:49:43.263         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
14:49:43.263         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
14:49:43.263         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
14:49:43.263         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
14:49:43.263         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
14:49:43.496             alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA driver found 32 devices
14:49:43.496             alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA initialized
14:49:43.496                  pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x7fd53009cf08)
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
14:49:43.499         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
14:49:43.499           pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
14:49:43.499           pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.8 for Linux-5.3.0.53/x86_64/glibc-2.27 initialized
14:49:43.499           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.262 MainThread __main__.main thread started
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.499 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test after libInit(ep_cfg)
14:49:43.499           pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.500 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test after libStart()
14:49:43.500         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
14:49:43.500           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.510 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 0 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.520 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 1 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.531 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 2 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.541 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 3 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.551 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 4 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.562 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 5 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.572 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 6 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.582 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 7 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.593 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 8 (0 events processed)
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:43.603 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test iter_count 9 (0 events processed)
14:49:43.604           pjsua_core.c  Shutting down, flags=0...
14:49:43.604           pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: RUNNING --> CLOSING
14:49:43.610           pjsua_call.c  .Hangup all calls..
14:49:43.610          pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: deinitializing media..
14:49:43.610          pjsua_media.c  .Call 1: deinitializing media..
14:49:43.610          pjsua_media.c  .Call 2: deinitializing media..
14:49:43.610          pjsua_media.c  .Call 3: deinitializing media..
14:49:43.610           pjsua_pres.c  .Shutting down presence..
14:49:44.610           pjsua_core.c  .Destroying...
14:49:44.610          pjsua_media.c  .Shutting down media..
14:49:44.997      sip_transaction.c  .Stopping transaction layer module
14:49:44.997      sip_transaction.c  .Stopped transaction layer module
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" unregistered
14:49:44.997      sip_transaction.c  .Transaction layer module destroyed
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" unregistered
14:49:44.997         sip_endpoint.c  .Endpoint 0x7fd5300087b8 destroyed
14:49:44.997           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CLOSING --> NULL
14:49:44.997           pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA destroyed...
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:44.997 PJSUA-THREAD __main__.pjsua2_test after ep.libDestroy()
DEBUG 2020-05-31,14:49:45.000 MainThread __main__.<module> after main()
```